# Unable to print the second field using awk filter passing in an AWS SSM Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, ssm

I am trying to get the details from the AWS SSM Parameter store. I have the data stored for which the value in SSM parameter store like this:

**CompanyName\credits**

Please find the SSM command executed through AWS CLI, the output is as follows:

````
aws ssm get-parameters --names "/Data/Details"

 - Output

{
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "Name": "/Data/Details",
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "CompanyName\\Credits",
            "Version": 1,
            "LastModifiedDate": "2019-08-13T18:16:40.836000+00:00",
            "ARN": "arn:aws:ssm:us-west-1:8484848448444:parameter/Data/Details"
        }
    ],
    "InvalidParameters": []
}  ```


In the above output, I am trying to print only **Credits** in **"Value": "CompanyName\\Credits"**, so I have added more filters to my command as follows:

``` aws ssm get-parameters --names "/Data/Details" |grep -i "Value" |sed -e 's/[",]//g' |awk -F'\\' '{print $2}' ```


The above command gives nothing in the output. But when I am trying to print the first field I am able  to see the output as  ** Value: CompanyName ** using the following command:

``` aws ssm get-parameters --names "/Data/Details" |grep -i "Value" |sed -e 's/[",]//g' |awk -F'\\' '{print $1}' ```


Since this is Linux machine, the double slash in the field **Value : CompanyName\\Credits ** occurred to escape the '\' character for the actual value CompanyName\Credits. Can someone let me know how can I modify the command to print only the value **Credits** in my output.

Regards,
Karthik
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
param_info=$(aws ssm get-parameters \
    --names "/Data/Details" \
    --query 'Parameters[0].Value' \
    --output text)

echo ${param_info} | awk -F'\\' {'print $3'}

# or without awk

echo ${param_info#*\\\\}  # for Credit
echo ${param_info%\\\\*}  # for CompanyName
```

This uses [query and output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html) parameters to control output from the aws cli. Also [bash parameter expansions](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-parameter-expansion) are used.

Comment: Thanks Marcin that worked. I am not sure why the commands executed by me earlier was not worked.

Comment: @karthik Don't know either, but this solution seems cleaner to me. And if you have `jq`, then `jq` could also be helpful.